# Replacing Non-Constant Elements from List with Pattern

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a list

```
list = {0, 0}, 0, {0, 0}, 0, 1}, {{0, 0}, 0, {0, 0}, 0, 2}, {{7,7}, 20, {7, 7}, 3}, {{8,8}, 30, {8, 9}, 4}}
```

And I want to remove all elements which have zeros but which also include the changing integer.

Attempt:

```
list2 = DeleteCases[list, {{0, 0}, 0, {0, 0}, 0, _Integer}];
```

The above code only removes the integer.

So I should be left with

```
list2 = {{7,7}, 20, {7, 7}, 3}, {{8,8}, 30, {8, 9}, 4}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `{{` at the beginning of `list`

*Mathematica* should have given you the following warning if you clicked on the red plus sign to the right of the cell:

> Syntax::bktmop: Expression "list={0,0},0,{0,0},0,1}" has no opening
>   "{".

```
list = {{{0, 0}, 0, {0, 0}, 0, 1}, {{0, 0}, 0, {0, 0}, 0, 2}, 
        {{7, 7}, 20, {7, 7}, 3}, {{8, 8}, 30, {8, 9}, 4}}
list2 = DeleteCases[list, {{0, 0}, 0, {0, 0}, 0, _Integer}]
```

> {{{7, 7}, 20, {7, 7}, 3}, {{8, 8}, 30, {8, 9}, 4}}

Comment: That is correct. Any suggestions to make that more clear would be appreciated. :)

Comment: @Tomi So what is the question exactly?  You seem to already have a solution.